# Simple & Customizable tooltip plugin wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I'm looking for a simple and customizable tooltip plugin, either plain javascript or Jquery based, which has these features:

- Bug free (Some that I've tried only show the tooltip sporadically and if you wave your mouse around they stop displaying)
- Customizable (i.e being able to customize the css of the tooltip, select how long the tooltip stays in place after the mouse moves away, etc)
- Must be able to programatically show/hide tooltips above any element, not just when the mouse is hovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that qTip does what you are looking for. I've used it on several projects without problems.  It's customizable and has a well documented api that allows you to show/hide it anywhere.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for something like this plugin -> http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

Ive used it myself in the past and it has some easy to customize features. You can see the demo with the available options here -> http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI has a tooltip that's to be included in 1.9 (not that I am the hugest fan of UI)

it might be worth checking out, I used it awhile ago (when it was even more beta) and it worked well enough  URL: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip

Answer (score 1):

i've made a simple and easy customizable one: http://piscolabis.es/proyectos/piscotooltip/

Comment: Does it only work on links? or any element?

Comment: Also is there a way to programatically show/hide the tooltip, not just when the mouse hovers over something?

Comment: Is pretty simple modify the code to do work with any elements (not only links); and to put the option to work with click and not only hover.
For click behaviour change the line: $(this).hover(function() for: $(this).click(function() 
And add a method to close the bubble inside the bubble.
Anyway thanks for the suggestion and i will try to add both